# Are there effects of chlorine on abrasions?

Tags: risks, sports, swimming, chlorine, abrasion-cut-laceration

Assume you happen to have some abrasions on your arm or leg and you want to swim in a swimming pool with chlorine.

- Does the contact with chlorine have negative (or positive) effects regarding healing and infection risks?
- (Will the abrasions hurt because of the chlorine?)

Comment: From personal experience I'll say no, but that's just my experience. Pain is a subjective thing so I don't think there's a verifiable right or wrong answer to this question. Voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: Are you asking about the possibility of chlorine causing problems like slowing healing or encouraging infection? Or are you asking about the possible discomfort and pain that chlorinated water contacting the abrasion could cause?

Comment: @Kris Thanks, I edited the question.